# Having issues Elasticsearch creating numeric field from parsed values for range query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an input of phone number which could include -, + or alphabet. I want to have a numeric version of that value for my Range query. So I was able to parse +233-333-3444 into 2333333444 and when I did a "match query" with "phone-num.parsedValue = 23333334444" i received results.

```
"phone-num": {

"text",

"fields": {

"parsedValue": {

"analyzer": "phone-analyzer",

"type":"text"

}}}
```

When i tried to do a range query:

```
"query":{

"range":{

"phone-num.parsedValue":{

"from":1,

"to": 2333333444,

"include_lower":true,

"include_upper":true }}}
```

i get 0 results. I am pretty sure this is because the value is in string. The issue is I am not sure how to query against it. I tried "copy_to" and "fields within fields" but neither worked... Is there a way to either:

1. Save another value based on my "parsedValue" result and save it as long so i can search against it
2. If I can't do it during mapping part, what about parsing as part of the query?

So to recap - I want to perform Ranged query on incoming Phone numbers with non-numeric values. I did filter it with custom analyzer to remove non-digits but can't search against it due to the result value still being a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead keep the parsed value field as a keyword field and just use a range query on that.

Here's an example of the mapping you could use:

```
PUT phone-numbers-index 
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "digits-only": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": "digits-only"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        
      },
      "char_filter" : {
        "digits-only":{
            "type":"pattern_replace",
            "pattern":"[^0-9]",
            "replacement":""
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "phone-num": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "digits-only": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "digits-only"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will create a field called "digits-only" on your phone-num field. Then, you can use a range query on the digits-only field to query phone numbers between two values:

```
GET phone-numbers-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "phone-num.digits-only": {
        "gt": "1",
        "lte": "2333333444"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query will return every document with a phone number greater than 1 and less than or equal to (233) 333-3444

Comment: I tried it and i don't think it is searching correctly
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "phone-num.digits-only": {
        "gt": "2333333444",
        "lte": "2333333444"
      }
    }
  }
}
gets me 0.  BUT if i change lte to something like 222222222222222222, i get some results. I don't think it is being treated as numbers?

Comment: don't make "gt" and "lte" the same value. "gt" means "greater than" and "lte" means "less than or equals". If you set both to the same value, you'll get zero results. use the exact query I gave you without changing it.

Comment: i did. so the issue is still if i search "gt": "1" "lte:22222222" i get some results. BUT if i use "gt:4" and same lte i get 0 results... somehow it is still thinking the keys are string.

Comment: Yes, they are still stored as strings, but you can still perform a range query on them this way. The difference is that they are sorted alphabetically rather than numerically, so "4" is greater than "2333333444".

Comment: hmm.. so how do i solve queries like 4045555 to 2034445555? I understand there are standards for phone numbers but with country codes etc. things could be different. is there another way to do it with fields during mapping using scripts maybe I can create a "long" field parsing with script? 
Also, why is there a need for "keyword" inside fields? it's not being used anywhere?